# Installing Ingres Database on Mac OS X 10.10

Tags: c++, macos, osx-yosemite, ingres

I need help - I am using MacBook Pro with Yosemite installed. I started next year in College and we have subject about databases. My tutor wants us to use Ingres database, but there is no release for Mac (there is release for Windows, Linux and even Solaris).

I googled for any community installer/package but I only found very old tutorials on building it yourself from source code. Still I did not found any clear step by step tutorial on how to do it and what compilers are required.

Could you please tell me how to install Ingres on mac or point me to a good tutorial? Other than

http://community.actian.com/wiki/Building_ingres_on_mac
http://community.actian.com/wiki/OSX_Installer

Cause I don't really understand them. Please help if you can. Thanks

Comment: Ask on https://apple.stackexchange.com

Comment: Try installing VirtualBox (which is free and easy to use) and running Windows XP or Ubuntu Linux on it.

Comment: I would go a step further and bootcamp your MBP to have a separate partition, then you can choose whether to boot into windows or mac. There are no restrictions on your windows os when you do it this way, virtual machines can be tricky at random especially for the purpose of installing software. Though, either should work.

Answer (score 1):

I've no experience with Ingres directly, but have you considered a virtual machine setup such as Vagrant? You could then run your Ingres server in a Linux VM, and simply forward the ports to your host machine.